# Can we change the default user in sqoop2

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I need to import data from Mysql to HDFS. Found this link helpful  http://devslogics.blogspot.com/2013/09/sqoop-java-client.html?showComment=1399588094791#c7484088811270691337. 
I am trying to create a new HDFS location and sqoop job fails as its having access denied issues. My question is: Can we change the default user? Here default user is sqoop2. Can we set it to our desired user?
I am using the callback method to submit the job

```
submission = client.startSubmission(jobId, new SubmissionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void updated(MSubmission submission) {
                }

                @Override
                public void submitted(MSubmission submission) {
                }

                @Override
                public void finished(MSubmission submission) {
                    Log.info("Job finished");
                }
            }
                    , pollTime);
```

Here is the error I found in the logs after running the job.

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=sqoop2, access=WRITE, inode="/xxx/xxxxxx/xlocation":hdfs:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4846)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4828)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:4802)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3094)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3075)
```

Thanks in advance